# The form does not send any data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When I try to send data using Form it does not work but when I send data using JSON it works good.

and in the Front-End it throws error status code 400

How do I solve this problem?

I've attached the response screenshots of JSON and Form for reference.

[When I use Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2S2T.png)
[when i use JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZnbw.png)

Here's the code for controller,schema and app.js

App.js

```
import express from "express";
import userRoutes from "./routes/user.js";
import brandRoutes from "./routes/brand.js";
import modelRoute from "./routes/vehicle.model.js";
import serviceRoute from "./routes/service.js";
import appointmentRoute from "./routes/appointment.js";
import categoryRoute from "./routes/category.js";
import { connectDB } from "./utils/dbConnect.js";
import { errorMiddleware } from "./middlewares/error.js";
import cors from "cors";
import "dotenv/config";

const PORT = 8000;

connectDB();

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use("/api/v1", userRoutes);
app.use("/uploads", express.static("uploads"));

app.use(errorMiddleware);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server connected at port ${PORT}`);
});
```

User.js

```
export const createUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { fullname, email, phone, password } = req.body;
    console.log(req.body);

    if (!fullname || !email || !phone || !password) {
      return next(new ErrorHandler("Please add all fields", 400));
    }

    const validate = await User.find({
      $or: [{ email: email }, { phone: phone }],
    });
    if (validate.length === 0) {
      const hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
      const user = await User.create({
        fullname: fullname,
        email: email,
        phone: phone,
        password: hashPassword,
      });
      if (user) {
        res.status(200).json({ status: 1, message: "Account created.", user });
      }
    } else {
      res.status(400).json({ status: 0, message: "User already exist." });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({ status: 0, message: "Error", error });
  }
};
```

User.js

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const schema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    fullname: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please enter your Fullname."],
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please enter your Email."],
    },
    phone: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please enter your Phone number."],
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please enter your Password."],
    },
    role: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["admin", "user"],
      default: "user",
    },
    image: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

export const User = mongoose.model("User", schema);
```

```
What are the possible solutions for this problem?
```

Comment: `app.use(express.json());` parses JSON request bodies. If you want to parse a form-urlencoded body, you need to add https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/express-js-express-urlencoded-function/, I think.

Comment: middleware `body-parser` is what you need.  see https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser